# How to add gems into Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, rubygems, logstash

I am running Logstash 1.4.1, comparing to the latest, I can't find anywhere in my installation folders contains gem information (versus the latest code in github has those gembag.rb, Gemfile etc..)

My current issue is I need to use several gems that Logstash doesn't have out of box, simply `require 'gemname'` seems doesn't work. Could anyone direct me to the readings that explains how to add these 3rd party gems or show me some sample codes which can do this.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
cd /opt/logstash
env GEM_HOME=vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9 GEM_PATH="" java -jar vendor/jar/jruby-complete-1.7.11.jar -S gem install gemname
```

If you're installing a local gem file, put the path to the file in GEM_PATH.

Comment: That's a fantastic solution @Alain. I guess even with latest logstash this is still doable?

Comment: I just did this on my 1.4.0 logstash install.  The latest is 1.4.2, which shouldn't have changed too much...

Comment: just confirmed it is running on 1.4.2 as well

Comment: Alex Simenduev's simple answer works at least with more recent versions of Logstash.

Answer (score 8):

I think the simplest way is:

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/ruby -S gem install <gem-name>
```

or

```
/opt/logstash/bin/ruby -S gem install <gem-name>
```

Work for me on recent version of logstash...

Comment: Works well on Windows too.

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me in logstash 2.0.

```
env GEM_HOME=/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9 /opt/logstash/vendor/jruby/bin/jruby /opt/logstash/vendor/jruby/bin/gem install PACKAGE_NAME -v PACKAGE_VERSION
```

Then I had to edit `/opt/logstash/Gemfile` to include the line:

```
gem "PACKAGE_NAME", "PACKAGE_VERSION"
```

I know we also did a `yum install ruby-devel` at some point along the way, but I don't remember if that was needed for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
env GEM_HOME=vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9 vendor/jruby/bin/jruby vendor/jruby/bin/gem install zookeeper -v 1.4.11 -V
```

edit Gemfile:

```
gem "zookeeper", "1.4.11"
```