# Installing mysql gem in logstash

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems, logstash

I am trying to install a few gems into Logstash 1.4.2

For this i googled and found a SO answer ([how to add gems into logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984620/how-to-add-gems-into-logstash))

After following the answer, I could install sequel gem easily.

But when I tried to install mysql gem like this:

```
cd logstash-1.4.2/
env GEM_HOME=vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9 GEM_PATH="" java -jar vendor/jar/jruby-complete-1.7.11.jar -S gem install mysql
```

I received following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    java -jar /home/deepak/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/jar/jruby-complete-1.7.11.jar extconf.rb
NotImplementedError: C extension support is not enabled. Pass -Xcext.enabled=true to JRuby or set JRUBY_OPTS.

   (root) at file:/home/deepak/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/jar/jruby-complete-1.7.11.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:8
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1085
   (root) at file:/home/deepak/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/jar/jruby-complete-1.7.11.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
   (root) at extconf.rb:5


Gem files will remain installed in /home/deepak/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/deepak/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

I am pretty new with ruby, so I didnt know what was missing here, I tried to add -Xcext.enabled=true

```
 env GEM_HOME=vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9 GEM_PATH="" java -jar vendor/jar/jruby-complete-1.7.11.jar -S -Xcext.enabled=true gem install mysql
```

But, that gave me another error :

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Xcext
  const_missing at org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2690
         (root) at -Xcext.enabled=true:1
```

Also, I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. And please comment if more information is needed.