# Parse complex XML file using ELK

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I recently started learning ELK but having hard time in understanding on how to parse XML data.
I would like to parse my XML file who looks like that:

```
<Name nameID="xxxx">
  <Type p="1">xxxxxx</Type>
  <Type p="2">xxxxxx</Type>
    .
    .
  <Type p="9">xxxxx</Type>
  <Value obj="1"> 
    <r p="1">5.94</r>
    <r p="2">62.19</r>
    .
    .
    <r p="9">7.19</r>
  </Value>
  <Value obj="2"> 
    <r p="1">5.94</r>
    <r p="2">62.19</r>
    .
    .
    <r p="9">7.19</r>
  </Value>
</Name>
<Name nameID="yyyy">
  <Type p="1">yyyyy</Type>
  <Type p="2">yyyyyy</Type>
  <Type p="3">yyyy</Type>
  <Value obj="1"> 
    <r p="1">54.94</r>
    <r p="2">6.19</r>
    <r p="3">0</r>
  </Value>
</Name>
```

I would like to get something like that: in the output

```
"NameID = name1
Type = Type1
obj = obj1
Value = xx
"
"NameID = name1
Type = Type2
obj = obj1
Value = xx
"
"NameID = name1
Type = Type3
obj = obj1
Value = xx
"
...etc
and then
"NameID = name1
Type = Type1
obj = obj2
Value = xx
"
"NameID = name1
Type = Type2
obj = obj2
Value = xx
"
....etc
```

I used this logstash.conf but I didn't get what I really need (I get an array for each field)

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/test/data.xml"
        start_position => beginning
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        codec => multiline
        {
            pattern => "<Name"
            negate => true
            what => "previous"
        }
    }
}
filter
{
    xml {
        source => "message"
        target => "parsed"
        add_tag => "xml"
        xpath => [
            "//Name/@nameID","Name",
            "//Type/@p","TypeID",
            "//Type/text()","Type",
            "//Value/@obj","Obj",
            "//r/text()","value"]
```

Comment: You can use ingest attachment plugin to do that easily, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/ingest-attachment.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```
filter { xml { source => "message" store_xml => true target => "theXML" force_array => false } }
split { field => "[theXML][Type]" }
split { field => "[theXML][Value]" }
split { field => "[theXML][Value][r]" }
```

and then use in the output:

```
output{
if [theXML][Type][p]==[theXML][Value][p]{
elasticsearch ....}}
```

hope that could help someone ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the logstash [ruby filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html). (need to [require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984620/how-to-add-gems-into-logstash) a gem in your code?)
2. with ruby [parse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11219941/155293) the XML, to
3. build the json document ready for index

Comment: Hi panchicore, I looked all day for same examples to use ruby filter plugin. But I didn't find a way to use it. In fact I don't know how to use it to solve my problem. Can you give me a suggestion? Thanks a lot ^^

Comment: the filter receives the var `event`, with it you access to the xml string, here is a simple example on how to flatten fields into an array https://github.com/panchicore/es-gtd/blob/master/logstash/ls-gtd-pipeline.conf#L36 start from here