# How to handle errors in Ruby while connecting to Redis?

Tags: ruby, error-handling, redis, logstash

I have a code in Ruby (as a Logstash plugin) in which I connect to Redis and get information like what is suggested in ([How to use redis inside logstash filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58379149)) as below:

```
require "redis"
$redis = Redis.new(host: "REDIS_HOST", port: REDIS_PORT, db: REDIS_DB)

@my_data = $redis.hget("DATA_KEY", "HASH_FIELD").to_i
```

Everything works OK generally; however, I want to know:

1- Which possible errors might be faced by the code while connecting to Redis or getting data (e.g. Redis is unreachable or DATA_KEY or HASH_FIELD does not exist)

2- How should we handle such errors?

Comment: https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/master/lib/redis/errors.rb is a list of potential errors

Comment: Basics of error handling: https://rollbar.com/guides/ruby/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-ruby/