# How to Generate monotonically increasing number which reset daily

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, logstash, streaming, sequential

So i am working on a project which converts non-structured logs into structured which is received in near real time stream in micro-batches of 2 seconds. 
Application writes event logs. Each log has one field inside its message which is event id. Using this event id we can segregate different event. 
In each event number of fields which needs to be extracted is different. For example if event id is 1 then by parsing that log we are getting 5 useful fields. In Event id 2 it may be 10. Also the meaning of fields are also subject to event. What ever value we get from position 2 of event id 1 it is absolutely different from the value we get from position 2 of event id 2. Resulting in separate schema for each event id. 
I want to store this event in parquet so i have to specify strict schema. For that i am segregating all the event and later on casting events to appropriate schema. But in this case i am loosing the sequence in which all the events arrived or occurred. I guess this should be very formal and standard problem in making data structured. How can we tackle this situation efficiently and reliably. I am using logstash->kafka->spark-streaming stack.

one solution i thought is, I can add the increasing counter to each message. Due to some reasons i can not add this increasing number when events are generated. I have to handle it in logstash or kafka or spark-streaming. As kafka and spark-streaming is distributed. We maintaining single sequence counter is difficult it seems(Wanted suggetion for this also).

So i think to add it in logstash. I think of the following solution. To have one counter and increase it by one. But due to heavy load it may surpass this number in some time. We have very less updates so may be once i start logstash it may go up to 5 years in single start. Which can also lead to reach max limit.

**Q1) So i am think of to implement counter such that it will reset to 0 at the end of day. As our data is partitioned on the day bases. Tried to implement in the following manner but drawback is every time i have to increase i have to check condition. Is there any better approach to handle this situation?**

```
# I tested i have around 5000 messages coming in single second
seqCounter = 0

def increase():
   seqCounter +=1
   if (current_time == day_end_time): # checking this condition will add overhead it seems.
      seqCounter = 0
```

**Q2) There is one issue with reliability also. As system can fail or due to some reason logstash restart is required then also will loose the current sequence. When it will restart it will start from 0. To handle this we can cache the current sequence but i guess it will add potential io delays as at every increment number need to be updated in file. Also it will cause duplicate sequence number. Is there any better approach to handle this situation?**

**Q3) I can use kafka offset but it is per-partition bases. So if single topic is sending data to multiple partitions(Which is in my case), offset will be repeated. Is there any better approach to handle this situation?**

**Q4) Instead of logstash is there any other solution to handle this kind of situation.**

** NOTE: In any of the solution major goal is to get back the sequence. The sequence number should be monotonically increasing so that i can get back event flow by sorting based upon that. Continuous sequence number is not needed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't your events have a timestamp? If yes, wouldn't it be possible to simply sort on that field?

Comment: @Val Thanks... I Used 12 digits of precision after second.  Still got around 4000 events from 20000 with same values. By checking further some values were for 4 times some values were 2 times. When time stamp will be same sorting will not garneted to sort in in-order.

Comment: How many events do you have per day approximately?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to generate this sequence number in Logstash would only work if Logstash has a **single worker** (i.e., `-w 1`), otherwise with several workers, events would not be processed in the order they are generated, but in parallel depending on how many workers there are.

That being said, by forcing Logstash to work with a single worker, you'd slow it down artificially, so it's not the best idea. Also, as you've rightly pointed out, you'd need to handle cases where Logstash breaks down or needs to be restarted.

That sequence number really needs to be something generated outside of Logstash. The first idea that comes to mind would be to use [Redis INCR](https://redis.io/commands/incr/) but there's no [official `redis` filter plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59300363/4604579).

Another idea would be to use an SQL sequence (for instance with [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html)) that you can easily query with the [`jdbc_streaming` filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-jdbc_streaming.html).

```
input {
   ...
}
filter {
  jdbc_streaming {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/path/to/jdbc-connector.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.product.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:xxsql://localhost:1234/mydatabase"
    jdbc_user => "me"
    jdbc_password => "secret"
    statement => "SELECT nextval('sequence');"
    target => "sequence"
  }
}
```

That would be a viable option only if you already have a DB that supports sequences, but not if you need to set one up just for this. Also depending on how many events per second are generated, having to query a remote DB for a sequence number might become a bottleneck.

Some plugins exist such as [this one](https://github.com/apenvern/logstash-filter-sequence), but the sequence value is only in memory and would be lost if Logstash restarts. You can also [create your own Java filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/filter-new-plugin.html) to generate an incrementing sequence value, but you'd still need to find a way to persist the value across restarts.

There are some ongoing issues (such as [#6997](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/6997)) that started working on that, but most of them are stale.

The best option you have remains to generate that sequence number right when events are being created.

Comment: Thanks @Val, As you said the best approach will be to add number at generation time only. But as it can causes so many design changes it it tough to implement. Some how that thing needs to be taken care after wards.  You are right having single worked will provide less throughput but if i will distribute the messages on multi worker cluster any how i will loose the sequence. Maintaining sequence is prime goal here. So i think of to go with single worked with high resources. I can use redis INCR but it will add delay of api calls. (cont...)

Comment: Also in my case around 20000 messages can come in single second. So this much read and update operation. May the better approach will be to maintain a file in high speed flash storage don't know the cons of it.. . Also same case will be with postgress.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I didn't quite get why you need to be able to sort your events in the same order they were produced

Comment: The main problem is not continues sequence. I want something using which we can clearly say that this message is generated before another message. Any functionality which can support this is fine. @Val may it help you to provide other solutions like above.

Comment: `that this message is generated before another message` You mean for a given event type (id = 1, 2, 3, etc)?

Comment: Order matters because of real time analytics. We want to implement anomaly detection and root cause analyzer.  Which will not have conditional statements for each use case or anomaly. Instead using deep learning the algo will try to find out pattern of event flow like Ev1->Ev2->Ev7->Ev9 is the flow. If Ev1->Ev2->Ev10 occurs may be its abnormal.

Comment: that this message is generated before another message You mean for a given event type (id = 1, 2, 3, etc)? ==> Yes, sometimes also want to know which message generated first before other in same event id also. Because EV1 is general other parameters in message will distinguish them

Comment: But the different timestamps alone are inherently supposed to define such sequences, right? The fact that ev2 happens after ev1 means their timestamps follow each other

Comment: Yes I generated 20000 events in a second. Stores time stamp with 12 digits of precision after second. HH:mm:ss.xxxxxxxxxxxx but still around 4000 messages had same time stamp in group of two or 4 messages with same stamp.

Comment: But the different timestamps alone are inherently supposed to define such sequences, right? The fact that ev2 happens after ev1 means their timestamps follow each other ==> This is not guaranteed that's why we cant implement rule based logic

Comment: 20K events in one second with 12 digits precision... are those just test events or real life events taken from a real world scenario?

Comment: No testing scenario, I just  wanted to check feasibility of "Can we get same timestamp or not?" Because if we are getting it then it will not work. And that's what happened. Because of this we can guarantee that in real time will not get same timestamp.

Comment: Ok, so you're optimizing for a situation that might never really happen in real life

Comment: Ha ha, Ya may be... Because of fact that if it can occurs for 4000 in 20000, Then i may get 1 in lets say 700-1000. But if it occurs for edge cases also. I want to avoid it if possible some how.

Comment: I am new to this. Wanted your suggestion, should i worried about this edge case??. Also i want this problems solution to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77325664/how-to-segregate-and-handle-mixup-of-various-schema-data-and-store-in-parquet-us) also.

Comment: So this is a new system that you're designing and that hasn't yet produced any single event, correct?

Comment: Event Is generated by micro-services around 50-70 and thats in prod since last 10 years. Analytics part is new that why i cant add sequence number at the time of generation. Currently as a part of traditional logging log files are used to retain it. We want to perform real time or near real time analytics over same event logs.

Comment: From those existing and real event logs, can you find two lines that have the exact same picosecond precision (i.e. 12 digits)? If picosecond precision is at all possible to achieve on conventional hardware...

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with accepting a compound 160-bit field (one int, two longs) Quality's [unique_id](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/0.1.3-SNAPSHOT/advanced/rowIdFunctions/#guaranteed-unique-id-how) provides a unique id, it's requirements are pretty simple (unique mac addresses for your cluster nodes and you don't rollback time on the driver node).

The benefits are it's always incrementing, related inserts are stored together, and it's fast for both storage and retrieval.